# Mail shows disconnected icon. Only way to recover is toggle Wifi

Tags: wifi, mail.app, email, gmail

Many times a day, Mail.app indicates it is unable to connect to my Gmail account.  I have tried quitting and restarting Mail, but it still shows disconnected.  If I toggle Wifi off then on, Mail is able to reconnect.  A few hours may go by and the problem occurs again.  Running OS X 10.11.3.  I have tried rebuilding the mailboxes using Onyx. Here are the Console logs for Mail:

```
3/13/16 12:24:41.941 AM Mail[5265]: {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
3/13/16 12:24:42.028 AM Mail[5265]: [IMAP] Got Error Domain=MCMailErrorDomain Code=1030 "The IMAP command “AUTHENTICATE” failed with server error: Invalid credentials (Failure)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The IMAP command “AUTHENTICATE” failed with server error: Invalid credentials (Failure).} for command IMAPAuthenticateCommand "AUTHENTICATE" <0x7fa253d7bd50> (3.1043 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 *****
)
3/13/16 12:24:42.029 AM Mail[5265]: XOAUTH2 requires user
3/13/16 12:24:42.029 AM Mail[5265]: Failed to start the SASL connection
SASL(-1): generic failure: XOAUTH2 requires user
3/13/16 12:24:42.029 AM Mail[5265]: No worthy mechs found
3/13/16 12:24:42.030 AM Mail[5265]: No worthy mechs found
3/13/16 1:57:41.112 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/Drafts because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 1:57:50.870 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for Sent Messages because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 1:57:51.567 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 1:57:58.487 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 1:58:00.079 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for INBOX because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 4:48:26.645 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for INBOX because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 4:48:26.645 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for Sent Messages because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 5:49:29.215 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/Drafts because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 5:49:32.891 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 5:49:33.418 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/Drafts because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 5:49:36.418 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 5:49:56.598 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for INBOX because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 5:49:56.598 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for Sent Messages because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 6:51:04.802 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/Drafts because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 6:51:15.571 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 6:51:17.356 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 6:51:21.325 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for Sent Messages because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 6:51:36.594 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for INBOX because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 7:03:21.025 AM sandboxd[134]: ([5265]) Mail(5265) deny iokit-set-properties IOAudioControlValue
3/13/16 7:06:17.565 AM Mail[5265]: Failed to open emlx and partial.emlx files (/Users/laura/Library/Mail/V3/5592AD44-7A2F-4893-AF88-DCFD1FA00027/[Gmail].mbox/All Mail.mbox/A14B71D7-0674-4EA8-817E-E9ECCE3B1E1F/Data/7/9/7/1/Messages/1797861.partial.emlx)
3/13/16 7:14:40.481 AM Mail[5265]: Failed to open emlx and partial.emlx files (/Users/laura/Library/Mail/V3/5592AD44-7A2F-4893-AF88-DCFD1FA00027/[Gmail].mbox/All Mail.mbox/A14B71D7-0674-4EA8-817E-E9ECCE3B1E1F/Data/7/9/7/1/Messages/1797875.partial.emlx)
3/13/16 7:22:54.898 AM sandboxd[134]: ([5265]) Mail(5265) deny iokit-set-properties IOAudioControlValue
3/13/16 7:23:20.379 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for INBOX because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 7:23:20.382 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for Sent Messages because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 7:23:20.382 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 7:23:20.383 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/Drafts because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 7:23:20.386 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/Drafts because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 7:23:20.386 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 7:23:43.082 AM Mail[5265]: Failed to open emlx and partial.emlx files (/Users/laura/Library/Mail/V3/5592AD44-7A2F-4893-AF88-DCFD1FA00027/[Gmail].mbox/All Mail.mbox/A14B71D7-0674-4EA8-817E-E9ECCE3B1E1F/Data/7/9/7/1/Messages/1797892.partial.emlx)
3/13/16 7:49:37.992 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for INBOX because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 7:49:45.997 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/Drafts because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 7:49:50.749 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for Sent Messages because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 7:49:51.868 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 7:49:51.868 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 8:18:25.343 AM sandboxd[134]: ([5265]) Mail(5265) deny iokit-set-properties IOAudioControlValue
3/13/16 8:18:27.303 AM Mail[5265]: {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
3/13/16 8:18:27.391 AM Mail[5265]: [IMAP] Got Error Domain=MCMailErrorDomain Code=1030 "The IMAP command “AUTHENTICATE” failed with server error: Invalid credentials (Failure)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The IMAP command “AUTHENTICATE” failed with server error: Invalid credentials (Failure).} for command IMAPAuthenticateCommand "AUTHENTICATE" <0x7fa2554d58f0> (3.1168 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 *****
)
3/13/16 8:18:27.392 AM Mail[5265]: XOAUTH2 requires user
3/13/16 8:18:27.392 AM Mail[5265]: Failed to start the SASL connection
SASL(-1): generic failure: XOAUTH2 requires user
3/13/16 8:18:27.393 AM Mail[5265]: No worthy mechs found
3/13/16 8:18:27.393 AM Mail[5265]: No worthy mechs found
3/13/16 8:48:31.356 AM sandboxd[134]: ([5265]) Mail(5265) deny iokit-set-properties IOAudioControlValue
3/13/16 9:03:54.644 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 9:03:56.702 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for Sent Messages because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 9:04:10.074 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for INBOX because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 9:58:24.352 AM sandboxd[134]: ([5265]) Mail(5265) deny iokit-set-properties IOAudioControlValue
3/13/16 10:09:23.117 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 10:09:32.797 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for Sent Messages because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 10:09:43.811 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for INBOX because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 10:09:44.161 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 10:53:10.885 AM CalendarAgent[252]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.mismatch] [Sync report for calendar home iCloud, failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fcadd25a8d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://laura.waldo%40gmail.com@p13-caldav.icloud.com/1616392295/calendars/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://laura.waldo%40gmail.com@p13-caldav.icloud.com/1616392295/calendars/, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://laura.waldo%40gmail.com@p13-caldav.icloud.com/1616392295/calendars/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://laura.waldo%40gmail.com@p13-caldav.icloud.com/1616392295/calendars/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}]
3/13/16 10:53:11.001 AM CalendarAgent[252]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.queue] [Account refresh failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={AccountName=iCloud, CalDAVErrFromRefresh=YES, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fcadd0b8270 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://laura.waldo%40gmail.com@p13-caldav.icloud.com/1616392295/principal/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://laura.waldo%40gmail.com@p13-caldav.icloud.com/1616392295/principal/, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://laura.waldo%40gmail.com@p13-caldav.icloud.com/1616392295/principal/, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://laura.waldo%40gmail.com@p13-caldav.icloud.com/1616392295/principal/, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8}]
3/13/16 10:53:11.091 AM sandboxd[134]: ([5265]) Mail(5265) deny iokit-set-properties IOAudioControlValue
3/13/16 11:55:49.050 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for Sent Messages because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 11:55:56.405 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for INBOX because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 11:56:12.374 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/Drafts because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 11:56:22.594 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 11:56:22.596 AM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 1:03:32.114 PM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 1:03:33.990 PM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for INBOX because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 1:03:41.595 PM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for Sent Messages because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 1:25:19.344 PM sandboxd[134]: ([5265]) Mail(5265) deny iokit-set-properties IOAudioControlValue
3/13/16 1:43:00.313 PM Mail[5265]: Failed to open emlx and partial.emlx files (/Users/laura/Library/Mail/V3/5592AD44-7A2F-4893-AF88-DCFD1FA00027/[Gmail].mbox/All Mail.mbox/A14B71D7-0674-4EA8-817E-E9ECCE3B1E1F/Data/7/9/7/1/Messages/1797932.partial.emlx)
3/13/16 1:43:11.702 PM Mail[5265]: Failed to open emlx and partial.emlx files (/Users/laura/Library/Mail/V3/5592AD44-7A2F-4893-AF88-DCFD1FA00027/[Gmail].mbox/All Mail.mbox/A14B71D7-0674-4EA8-817E-E9ECCE3B1E1F/Data/7/9/7/1/Messages/1797930.partial.emlx)
3/13/16 1:43:23.476 PM Mail[5265]: Failed to open emlx and partial.emlx files (/Users/laura/Library/Mail/V3/5592AD44-7A2F-4893-AF88-DCFD1FA00027/[Gmail].mbox/All Mail.mbox/A14B71D7-0674-4EA8-817E-E9ECCE3B1E1F/Data/7/9/7/1/Messages/1797925.partial.emlx)
3/13/16 1:49:35.348 PM sandboxd[134]: ([5265]) Mail(5265) deny iokit-set-properties IOAudioControlValue
3/13/16 1:56:24.393 PM sandboxd[134]: ([5265]) Mail(5265) deny iokit-set-properties IOAudioControlValue
3/13/16 2:19:15.352 PM sandboxd[134]: ([5265]) Mail(5265) deny iokit-set-properties IOAudioControlValue
3/13/16 2:19:15.733 PM Mail[5265]: Skipping STATUS for [Gmail]/All Mail because CHECK failed with error: (null)
3/13/16 2:20:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: SpotlightNetHelp(345) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/Mail.app
3/13/16 2:20:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: SpotlightNetHelp(345) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/Mail.app/Contents
3/13/16 2:20:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: SpotlightNetHelp(345) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/PkgInfo
3/13/16 2:20:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: SpotlightNetHelp(345) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
3/13/16 2:20:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: SpotlightNetHelp(345) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail/..namedfork/rsrc
3/13/16 2:20:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: SpotlightNetHelp(345) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/Mail.app
3/13/16 2:20:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: SpotlightNetHelp(345) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/Mail.app/Contents
3/13/16 2:20:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: SpotlightNetHelp(345) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/Mail.app
3/13/16 2:20:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: SpotlightNetHelp(345) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
3/13/16 2:20:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: SpotlightNetHelp(345) deny(1) file-read-data /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/PlugIns
```